# [HTML&CSS]Why CSS file doesn't apply to html? :/ :/

Tags: html, css

I write HTML file and CSS file and operate in Chrome but I think CSS file doesn't apply to HTML file...

I don't know why... but I think I documented code properly

here is directory 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqnd2.png)

and this is What Problematic code

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body {
  font-family:"맑은 고딕", "돋움";
  font-size:12px;
  color:#444444;
}
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}
.clear {
  clear:both;
}
#wrap {
  width:970px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
/* 상단 헤더 */
header {
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}
header #logo {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:20px;
}
header #top_menu {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:770px;
}
header #main_menu{
  width:757px;
  height:38px;
  background-image:url("../img/main_menu_bg.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:210px;
}
header #main_menu li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:12px 30px 0 50px;
  font-size:13px;
}
header #main_menu a:link {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
}
header #main_menu a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
}
header #main_menu a:visited {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
}
header #main_menu a:active {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
}
aside {
  width:190px;
  float:left;
}
aside #login_box {
  width:186px;
  heigth:120px;
  border:solid 1px #dddddd;
}
aside #login_title {
  margin:10px 0 0 10px;
}
aside #input_button {
  margin:10px 0 0 10px;
}
aside #login_input {
  float:left;
}
aside #login_btn {
  float:left;
  margin:3px 0 0 5px;
}
aside #login_input input {
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  border:solid 1px #dddddd;
}
aside #login_input li {
  margin-top:2px;
}
aside #join_search {
  margin: :10px 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>클래식기타 커뮤니티</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type=="text/css" href="/css/common.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" type=="text/css" href="/css/header.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" type=="text/css" href="/css/footer.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" type=="text/css" href="/css/main.css?">
</heda>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
  <header>
    <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png">
    <nav id="main_menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="board_list.html">자유 게시판</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">기타 연주</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">공동 구매</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">연주회 안내</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">회원 게시판</a><li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header> <!-- header -->
  <aside>
    <article id="login_box">
      <img id="login_title" src="img/ttl_login.png">
      <div id="input_button">
        <ul id="login_input">
          <li><input type="text"></li>
          <li><input type="password"></li>
        </ul>
        <img id="login_btn" src="img/btn_login.gif">
      </div>
    <article>
  </aside>
</div><!-- wrap -->
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvDtc.png)

so I want to know why CSS file doesn't work :/

Comment: What URL are you using to access your website?

Comment: you have to remove the starting `/` from all the CSS include rules: `/css/common.css` => `css/common.css`. That is not the best solution for including CSS files, but it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some problem with the file paths specified in the *link href* of the css files. Instead of mentioning "/css/common.css" if you write "css/common.css". The styles should load given the directory structure is as posted in the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the console of the browser you will most probably have the failing CSS includes and you will see from where it tries to load them.

By using `href="/css/common.css"` it tries to load the styles from the base domain so, for example if your URL to access the website is: `http://localhost/Ch12_Make_commuSite/index.html` the CSS files will be loaded from here: `http://localhost/css/common.css` which is definitely not correct.

It works exactly like the `src` for the images which you got correctly.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Here is a solution that should work

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body {
  font-family:"맑은 고딕", "돋움";
  font-size:12px;
  color:#444444;
}
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}
.clear {
  clear:both;
}
#wrap {
  width:970px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
/* 상단 헤더 */
header {
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}
header #logo {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:20px;
}
header #top_menu {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:770px;
}
header #main_menu{
  width:757px;
  height:38px;
  background-image:url("../img/main_menu_bg.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:210px;
}
header #main_menu li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:12px 30px 0 50px;
  font-size:13px;
}
header #main_menu a:link {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
}
header #main_menu a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
}
header #main_menu a:visited {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
}
header #main_menu a:active {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
}
aside {
  width:190px;
  float:left;
}
aside #login_box {
  width:186px;
  heigth:120px;
  border:solid 1px #dddddd;
}
aside #login_title {
  margin:10px 0 0 10px;
}
aside #input_button {
  margin:10px 0 0 10px;
}
aside #login_input {
  float:left;
}
aside #login_btn {
  float:left;
  margin:3px 0 0 5px;
}
aside #login_input input {
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  border:solid 1px #dddddd;
}
aside #login_input li {
  margin-top:2px;
}
aside #join_search {
  margin: :10px 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>클래식기타 커뮤니티</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type=="text/css" href="css/common.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" type=="text/css" href="css/header.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" type=="text/css" href="css/footer.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" type=="text/css" href="css/main.css?">
</heda>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
  <header>
    <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png">
    <nav id="main_menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="board_list.html">자유 게시판</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">기타 연주</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">공동 구매</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">연주회 안내</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">회원 게시판</a><li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header> <!-- header -->
  <aside>
    <article id="login_box">
      <img id="login_title" src="img/ttl_login.png">
      <div id="input_button">
        <ul id="login_input">
          <li><input type="text"></li>
          <li><input type="password"></li>
        </ul>
        <img id="login_btn" src="img/btn_login.gif">
      </div>
    <article>
  </aside>
</div><!-- wrap -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your css pathing used in the css, according to your screenshot you need to remove the  / from the start, also i adivce you to open the consil of chrome that way you cann see the pathing issue